# What is the difference between a conjunction and a preposition?

Tags: syntax, morphology, prepositions, conjunctions

What exactly is the difference between them?
I've seen people say that prepositions connect words and conjunctions connect syntagms and clauses. Is this definition accurate?
Is there any linguist who carefully explain this?

Answer (score 4):

**Conjuctions**, as you say, connect sentences and clauses, but also phrases and single words. Examples are `and`, `or`, `but`, `because`, `neither ... nor`, `rather ... than`, etc.
Single-word conjunctions are usually placed inbetween the two parts they combine, such as in `[the man] *and* [the woman]` or `[Mary is not at home] or [she is already asleep]`, multi-word conjunctions with the first part in front of the first conjunct and the second part in front of the second one (such as in `neither [do I want to talk] nor [do I have the time])`.
Conjunctions coordinate elements of the same type and of more or less equal imporatance, such as two sentences, two noun phrases, etc, where the conjoined phrase is of the same type as before (`[the man] and [the woman]` -> two noun phrases combine to a new noun phrase), `[Either we get some food] or [we go home]` -> two sentences combine to a new sentence).

**Prepositions** express relations, mostly w.r.t. time (`before`, `after`, `in`, ...) and place (`over`, `behind`, `into` etc.), but also other semantic roles (such as `of`, `to`, `for`).
Prepositions always combine with noun phrases (i.e. simple nouns, complex nouns and pronouns, such as `a house`, `the first half of the year`, `him`), which are called their complements.
Pre-positions occur by definition in front of their complement; a more general term is `adposition` (including both prepositions and postpositions, an example of the latter would be `ago`, however the vast majority of adpositions in English are prepositions). A prepositional phrase will therefore always have the form `Prep + noun phrase`.
Prepositional phrases add additional, usually optional information to a noun phrase or verb phrase, such as `the candles [on the table]`, `a gift [for him]` or `she left [before noon]`.

Some words may be able to function both as conjunctions and as prepositions, such as in Alex B.'s example `He left just before [sunrise]` (preposition) vs. `[He had left the house] before [I arrived]` (conjunction).

To summarise:

- Conjunctions connect sentences, clauses, phrase, single words of the same type and equal importance, where the conjoined phrase is of 
  the same type as the individual parts
- Prepositions express relations, mostly w.r.t time and place, and always occur in front of a noun phrase. Prepositional phrases
  usually add optional information to an action or object.

Comment: Well, another issue you didn't address is that **the same word can be used as a preposition** (He left just before sunrise.) **and a conjunction** (He had left the house before I arrived).

Comment: @AlexB., In **TSPE**, McCawley subscribes to Jespersen's theory that prepositions and subordinate conjunctions are the same POS.

Comment: @Greg Lee could you write that with their argumentation as an answer?

Comment: @Alex B. in both your cases it is preposition.

Comment: @AlexB., No, I refer you to McCawley for arguments.  But obviously there is sometimes a coincidence of form and meaning:  "after his departure" = "after he departs/departed".(as you pointed out above).

Comment: Preposition: 'He appeared before the judge.'  Subordinate conjunction: 'He arrived before the judge [arrived].'  Conjunction phrases that look like prepositional phrases have elided verbs.  They are not the same POS.

Comment: @GregLee  That is also the position of Huddleston & Pullum, *CGEL*.

Comment: @GregLee No problem. I was thinking about the OP (and other potential visitors to the site), not myself.

Comment: @StoneyB And that is a very sound position.

Comment: @Anixx just curious, how do you personally understand the difference (if any) between prepositions and conjunctions.

Comment: @lemontree Hmm, even in traditional grammars prepositions don't always occur before NP's. Consider *until* in the phrase *until recently* or *until after the concert is over*. Jespersen, Emonds and H&P all recognise intransitive Preps with no complements and preps with other types of complement.

Comment: @Araucaria Good point, so I guess the set of complements a prep can take should be extend from NPs to PPs and adverbial construtions (given that they express some temporal or local content)? I don't get the second part of your comment, though: What do you mean by intransitive preps with no complements?

Comment: @lemontree Well, loads of writers and many modern grammars recognise words such as *abroad, here, now* etc as a class of words that may not take complements but are the same type of word as prepositions. It's pretty convincing stuff.